# Do I need to synchronize an object's reference?

Tags: java, multithreading

I use *synchronized* for concurrent write/read operations on an object's values.

However, I'm not sure if I have to **synchronize the reference to an object**, that may be set and get concurrently.
Even though B below is an immutable object, the setter changes its reference and the getter might be called concurrently.

```
class A {
   private B b;

   public setB(B b) { this.b = b; }
   public getB() { return b; }
}
```

Do I need to synchronize the setter and the getter of B (the reference) (and if so, is the code below a good way to do it) ?

```
class A {
   private B b;
   private Object bLock = new Object();

   public setB(B b) { synchronized(bLock) { this.b = b; } }
   public getB() { synchronized(bLock) { return b; } }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need synchronization. After all, applying your own logic from the opening sentence tells you that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik sorry for coming back on this question, but I automatically assumed that if threads get/set a property concurrently, I ALWAYS need to synchronize to "protect" shared memory or something.. when it is actually just to guarantee consistency. However, in many cases I don't care about consistency, i.e. about the last state of a property. For example, imagine I get real-time data, multiple data per second, and an object holds a reference to that last data received. If I access this data and I don't get exactly the last one, I don't mind. Then I guess I can just leave this without sync

Comment: That is incorrect. Accessing data over a data race may result in never obtaining an updated value. A thread may live on forever with its stale local copy. Further, it is never appropriate to observe an object in a partially initialized state, which is another thing that may happen in a data race.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik but if I don't need the updated value, then I can let a data race happen, right? e.g. my example with real-time data, imagine the price of stocks, if I don't have the very last price, I don't mind, because this data is updated constantly and so frequently

Comment: I would propose that a difference exists between "late" and "never". And I cannot do any better but restate my earlier point: whichever instance of  `B` you observe, you will at least expect it to be in a fully initialized state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need synchronization.

You can use an [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) to synchronize the B object

Note that using AtomicReference in code which only needs its get and set methods is overkill---what you need is just ***volatile***

Comment: True, except that wouldn't be called "synchronization".

Comment: I didn't think about that. How would that be different with a synchronized?

Comment: No mutual exclusion of threads. But do note that using `AtomicReference` in code which only needs its `get` and `set` methods is overkill---what you need is just `volatile`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, the true value of `AtomicReference` lies in the `XXXandSet()` methods, if you just use `get()` and `set()`,  you can replace it with the cheaper `volatile`.

Comment: You are totally right @MarkoTopolnik, `volatile` is better because `AtomicReference` uses a spin locks

Comment: `get` and `set` actually don't do anything more than directly reading and writing the `volatile` value, and even `compareAndSet` doesn't use locks, but a CAS loop.